# Gradient not working on IE but works everywhere else

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, gradient

My gradient works in Firefox, Opera, Safari, etc, but does not work on IE.

My code is below can someone help me out:

```css
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #b49931), color-stop(0.5, #5E5E5E), color-stop(0.51, #707070), color-stop(1, #838383)); 
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #b49931 0%, #5E5E5E 50%, #707070 51%, #838383 100%); //FF 
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(center bottom, #b49931 0%, #5E5E5E 50%, #707070 51%, #838383 100%); //IE 
background-image: -0-linear-gradient(center bottom, #b49931 0%,#5E5E5E 50%, #707070 51%, #838383 100%); //opera
```

Comment: For Opera, it should be `-o-linear-gradient`. It's not called `0pera`.

Comment: The internet explorer is everytime a problem. Let it die...

Comment: "not working on IE but works everywhere else" that's the most common problem in web design

Comment: IE8...so there is no way around this at all?

Comment: No.  It really is ok to not make everything look identical 100% in every browser as long as they're still getting a good experience.  Does it hurt IE users to have a solid background instead of a gradient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000');
```

Comment: awesome works. how do I get 4 colours like:  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, #b49931 0%, #5E5E5E 50%, #707070 51%, #838383 100%); //FF